# When I try to save my numpy array to an .npy file I get a memory error. How can I create a large .npy file from image files with limited memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, memory, keras

I am new to working with large data sets. I would like to generate an .npy file with my training data. I have about 1.7GB worth of PNG images that I want to load, however due to memory errors I have divided this set up into chunks and I am now attempting to load only about 389.5 MB worth of PNG files into a numpy array and then save it. I am able to load the files into the array but when I attempt to save it I get a memory error. I have tried both .pickle and .npy file types. I am confused as to why this is a problem as my laptop has 8GB of RAM. I can see that there are some memory inefficiencies in my code but I have not found a way to get around them. How can I go about loading this data into a .npy file? And what is the best approach for me to also include the rest of my training data?

```py
def create_training_data():
    training_data = []
    IMAGE_SIZE = 640
    DATADIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'training_data')  # directory where training data is held
    CATEGORIES = ["0", "1"]
    count = 0
    fail = 0
    for category in CATEGORIES:

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):#
            count += 1
            print(str(count))
            try:

                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img))
                if not (img_array.shape[0] == IMAGE_SIZE and img_array.shape[1] == IMAGE_SIZE):
                    img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))

                training_data.append([img_array, class_num])

            except Exception:

                fail += 1
                print("failed "+str(fail)+"/"+str(count))

    random.shuffle(training_data)
    X = []
    y = []

    for features, label in training_data:

        X.append(features)
        print(str(features))
        y.append(label)
    # X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)
    np.save('training_data/X.npy', X)
    np.save('training_data/y.npy', y)
    # pickle_out = open("training_data/X.pickle", "wb")
    # pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
    # pickle_out.close()pytho
    # pickle_out = open("training_data/y.pickle", "wb")
    # pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
    # pickle_out.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Without really digging into your code... have you checked if [`keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) might solve your problem? Do you really need to save your training data or can you generate it on the fly?

Comment: This is a good suggestion to avoid memory problems all together - though I used the other solution as it seems that with the structure of my code as it is now the other solution will be quicker for me. However I will be sure to keep this in mind for next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pickle and `numpy.save` are too memory inefficient to save large datasets, I would recommend you to use [h5py](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html) to save data as HDF5, which is very efficient and should work under these constraints.

I have used it to save image datasets over hundreds of GB with low RAM usage.